# How can I retrieve specifc field without using loop in a return statement with MongoDB and Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, return, crud

I have below working code using for loop to iterate all the id in the user collection. Although this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141990/how-to-retrieve-a-single-field-from-mongodb-in-java) could help me to this question, it returns specific value as well. I wonder how to get the same result without using it because I can't complete the return statement.

```
@Override
public User get(Object userId) {

    FindIterable<User> userTbl = database.getCollection("User", User.class).find();
    for (User doc : userTbl) {

        String id = doc.getId().toHexString();
        System.out.println("_id = " + id);

        if (id.equals(userId)) {
            return doc;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What does 'because I can't complete the return statement' mean? Do you want to retrieve and return just a specific field of your user?

Comment: @Milgo  return just a specific field of the user... sorry for my context

Comment: You can use a query with predicate like this: `collection.find(new Document("_id", userId)).first();`. This returns a matching document or a `null`.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks, but how can I use it in the return method/statement?

Comment: I generally try to return `Wrapped Objects or Content Objects` however you want to call  in this case. To not avoid having to return a `null` which can cause a serious mistake when someone else uses your function in your code base; Have a look at this:. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138878/5801823

Comment: @prasad_ I tried your suggestion but only return the 1st record when I test on JUnit to different email address. :(

Comment: The method signature shown `User` as the returned object. So, you are returning one object only. That is why you use the `first`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to return one field, just do so.

```
@Override
public String get(Object userId) {

    FindIterable<User> userTbl = database.getCollection("User", User.class).find();
    for (User doc : userTbl) {

        String id = doc.getId().toHexString();
        System.out.println("_id = " + id);

        if (id.equals(userId)) {
            return doc.getUser();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But it should be easier to use a MongoRepository to get easier access to your data.

Repository example class (with Spring):

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

And your get() method:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public Optional<String> get(String userId) {

    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
    if (user.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.of(user.get().getId());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Spring data, but thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: No, the signature is User, the doc has no getUser() to call, this is why I got stuck somehow..., really appreciate your help but.